# How can I choose a specific location for Logic's 40GB of additional content?

Tags: partition, macos, logic

I have an SSD onto which I've installed the operating system OS X 10.10.1, as well as my applications. I also have a much larger and much slower internal HDD for storage and other rarely-accessed files.

I use Logic X for audio editing, and I have historically enjoyed having access to the 40GB of instruments and sounds referred to as "additional content" optionally available for download from the program menu.

When attempting to download the additional content, Logic informs me that there is not enough free disk space to download all 40GB, which is just as well, because even if I had the space I would prefer that these 40GB of additional content files remain on the HDD rather than the SSD.

How can I specify an alternate location in which to keep Logic's 40GB of additional content files?

If there is no such setting, would it be possible and/or advisable to create some kind of file system pointer for the additional content's folder, à la unix-style symbolic link, across different physical media? (or at least to another partition on the same physical disk?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer <s>stolen</s> borrowed [here](https://www.gearslutz.com/board/logic-pro-x/854440-how-install-logic-pro-x-content-external-hd.html):

1. Download this for free: [symbolic linker](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/10433/symboliclinker)
2. Copy original 'Logic' Folder located in /Volumes/"SSDVolumeName"/Library/Application Support/ on the desired external drive and location.This is the location where all your additional content is beeing installed to.
3. You can delete the original folder or rename it and use it as a backup.
4. Use the symbolic link tool to create a symbolic link from the 'Logic' file which has been copied to your external drive.
   Place the link (which looks like an alias) to its previous destination (/Volumes/"SSDVolumeName"/Library/Application Support/) and rename it to 'Logic'.
5. After this you will be able to download additional content.
6. Be aware if you want to download 30 GB of content and your SSD has just 20GB free space, it will show you the same error message because it stores the download file still on your SSD until installation is done. **The solution for this is to download everything part by part**."

   or:

   Using the Finders 'Go to Folder' menu option, enter:

   ```
   /private/var/folders/
   ```

   A look in the various folders there will reveal a folder called "com.apple.MusicApps/audiocontentdownload.apple.com/".
   Copy the folder "lp10_ms3_content_2013" to your external drive, delete the original and symlink this folder on your external drive back to /private/var/folders/../com.apple.MusicApps/audiocontentdownload.apple.com/ 
   If the folder "lp10_ms3_content_2013" is missing in the original just create it on your external drive and link it back.
   (**not tested**)

Comment: Tried the "not tested" option, and thankfully had a bootable thumbdrive. I think you need to specify that the person matches permissions on the symlinked `private/var/folders` in its new location. I created a folder with my regular user account, symlinked it, and when I rebooted my Mac I got a grey screen because some of the services need the group to be `wheel` I'm guessing. Hope this helps someone who looks at this second option optimistically without thinking. I too have not tested whether setting the correct permissions on the new folder works. I had to hard reset my machine & got spooked.